# Does an infinite dimensional Banach space always admit an infinite dimensional, separable subspace?

Tags: banach-spaces

If that can't be achieved, what if the Banach space is reflexive?

Comment: Take a sequence $x_n$ of linearly independent vectors; consider the  closure of their linear span.

Comment: How could you prove the closure is seperable?

Comment: As a separable dense subset, take linear combinations with rational coefficients.

Comment: I don't think the subset of linear combinations with rational coefficients is countable…

Comment: It is. I emphasize: _finite_ linear combinations.